# Chrome OS bug - file select dialog (for uploads) 'stuck'

Tags: file-upload, google-chrome-os, chromebook

The best way to sum up the issue would be with a screenshot, but unfortunately my screenshots auto-save to downloads and so I can't upload them. What's happening is that when I enter the 'file select' dialog in trying to upload a file, it's automatically in the 'drive' folder and won't move to any other folder. I've tried restarting and resetting my machine, tried the upload process on a bunch of different platforms, tried using the other user account on my machine, tried updating my software, but none of these have made any difference. I can get into my downloads folder and open files from it fine outside of this context, and I can workaround by using the drag-and-drop to upload on platforms which have this feature, but otherwise I'm stuck.

I've googled extensively to see if anyone else is having this issue and have found this thread: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/d7g9EEDsr8w but there's no helpful solution there (recommended a powerwash but the asker has already done this several times). I've also tried to find a solution with the help of my (programmer) employer, but no luck so he recommended asking here. It seems like it wouldn't be a hardware issue when I can still access the folder outside of this specific function, but if it were a problem with the running system it seems it would be happening across the board and therefore show up more in a google? If anyone has any suggestions I'd be very grateful as it's getting quite tiresome having to drag and drop things into Facebook messages to get them uploaded! The machine is less than a year old so if I can't find any solution I'll see about getting it replaced under warranty. Thanks in advance for any help, and please let me know if there's any key info I've left out!

Machine: Samsung Chromebook XE303C12
OS: Version 38.0.2125.110

Comment: No solution, but I'm also seeing this on an HP Chromebook 11

Comment: My wife is having this problem too all of a sudden in the past week or so. When I open the files menu, I see all her files. But when it's opened from the browser like when trying to upload photos to Facebook or something, then only a couple folders and two files show up. Not the hundreds of photos she has... If you figure out the issue, please let me know

Comment: @ThomShutt and Kevin M - this problem has just (over the last few days) stopped happening on my machine of its own accord, no idea why but here are my OS creds so you can check whether you're on the same version - could be they ironed it out in a recent update:

Version 39.0.2171.85
Platform 6310.48.0 (Official Build) stable-channel daisy
Firmware Google_Snow_Rev4.2695.128.0